Equivalent vba for python requests
I have the following python code
import requests

url = 'https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg/account/authenticate'
data = {'EmailAddress': '471666845@minia4.moe.edu.eg'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)

print('Final URL After Redirection:', response.url)

I need the vba equivalent for this code that prints the response url. In python, it prints something like that https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=e6ffeec9-aee3-480d-9d60-ddbdce181893&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fmoe-register.emis.gov.eg%2faccount%2ftrust&scope=openid%20email%20profile&response_mode=form_post&state=315db325-bdb7-4e8a-a7ac-0559970943a7&nonce=018c05a4-73f5-459b-8626-5ae5d1b3b0f6&login_hint=471666845@minia4.moe.edu.eg but in vba I didn't get this
this is the vba code
Sub Test()
    Dim http As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim status As Long
    Dim locationHeader As String
    Dim responseBody As String
    Dim maxRedirects As Integer
    Dim redirectCount As Integer
    url = "https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg/account/authenticate"
    email = "471666845@minia4.moe.edu.eg"
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    maxRedirects = 10
    redirectCount = 0
    Do
        http.Open "POST", url, False
        http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        http.send "EmailAddress=" & email
        status = http.status
        If status >= 300 And status < 400 Then
            locationHeader = http.getResponseHeader("Location")
            url = locationHeader
            redirectCount = redirectCount + 1
        Else
            responseBody = http.responseText
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop While redirectCount < maxRedirects
    MsgBox "Final URL After Redirection: " & url
    If Len(responseBody) > 1024 Then
        MsgBox "Response Body (First 1024 characters): " & Left(responseBody, 1024)
    Else
        MsgBox "Response Body: " & responseBody
    End If
    Set http = Nothing
End Sub


Maybe look at the WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects option for WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest   Also "in vba I didn't get this" tells us nothing about what you got instead of what you expected.

I need to get this output in vba response.url

I have found a solution to my problem
With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False
    .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString) = "curl"
    .Open "POST", "https://moe-register.emis.gov.eg/account/authenticate", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send "EmailAddress=" & sEmail
    sLocation = .getResponseHeader("Location")
End With

